# How to get hyperlinks in a matplotlib table?

Tags: matplotlib, svg, jupyter, matplotlib-table

I have a matplotlib table

```
ax.table(twoD_array_of_links)
```

where the links look like

```
     [['<a xlink:href="https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=PSMA6">PSMA6</a>',
       '<a xlink:href="https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=PSMA2">PSMA2</a>'],
      ['<a xlink:href="https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=PSMA4">PSMA4</a>',
       '<a xlink:href="https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=PSMA8">PSMA8</a>']]
```

I'm plotting as SVG in a jupyter notebook. I'm getting the links as text in the table.

- How do I get these matplotlib table cells to become hyperlinks in the saved SVG?
- How do I get these cells to become hyperlinks when they're displayed inline (as svg) in jupyter?